# Check if php file is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got simple jquery function which should delete a row from database, my script is:

> //
>
> ```
> // delete the entry once we have confirmed that it should be deleted
> $('.delete').click(function() {
>     var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
>
>
>     $.ajax({
>         type: 'get',
>         url: 'delete.php', // <- replace this with your url here
>         data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + $(this).attr('id'),
>         beforeSend: function() {
>             parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
>         },
>         success: function() {
>             parent.fadeOut(300,function() {
>                 parent.remove();
>             });
>         }
>     });        
> });
>
> // confirm that it should be deleted
> $('.delete').confirm({
>     msg:'Do you really want to delete this?',
>     timeout:3000
> });     }); // ]]></script>
> ```

Which when I click on bitton dalete row (on screen), but in database it's still exist, how to check if php is executed?
My php file:

```
> <?php     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); if (!$con)   {  
> die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }
> 
> mysql_select_db("xxx", $con);
> $sql="DELETE FROM
> `submission_values` WHERE  SubmissionId =49";   
> mysql_query($sql,$con);
> 
> ?>
```

What url I should give if it's in the same folder? Only name like it is above?
Should that work? (in delete.php)

> echo("alert('ok');");

Comment: look around for a js rpc client and php rpc service. avoid soap and xml in general, its too much for your needs, and for js performance.

Comment: Just return something from the server to show that the row was removed. What this has to do with soap and xml is beyond me ?

Comment: First, you should check if your Php code works by directly typing in your browser the url that delete a row. For example  `http://mywesite.com/delete.php?ajax=1&delete=20`, then check in your database if the previous element with id=20 is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

In your php file, you can echo out a response. Then using jQuery's response object, you can check the value of the response to see if the php script ran to that echo line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger some error condition on failure.

First, to check for failure, use this:

```
if( $e = mysql_error()) {/* report $e */}
```

Personally I like to return a JSON string containing whether or not the operation was successful and if not what error occurred - this allows you to differentiate between an HTTP issue (which is what `.success()` and `.error()` look for), and judge whether or not you should continue or die.

Comment: `.success` and `.error` are deprecated in jQuery 1.8. `.done` and `.fail` are preferred.

Comment: Well excuse me for not touching jQuery with a fifty-foot pole.

Comment: Oh yes, I was just commenting for future reference -- when people upgrade to jQuery 2.0 or so, `.success` and `.error` may be not present in the jQuery core anymore and require a compat plugin.